# How to copy text from an InputField to the clipboard in WebGL?

Tags: unity, webgl, unity-webgl

I would like to know if there is a solution to copy/paste the text from/to an InputField in a WebGL Unity app.

For security reasons, Unity WebGL doesn't allow text copy and paste in/from browser.

Comment: an input field of your own? one on another app (aka screen scraping?)

Comment: No, standard Unity InputField ; the problem of coping & pasting is a browser security issue

Comment: Yes.  It is possible.  What problem are you having?  https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.InputField-text.html

Comment: It would help if you edit your question to specify the nature of the security issue that is generating your problem: does it occur in both directions (i.e. copying from the browser & pasting to the browser), does it occur in multiple browsers, what happens when you try to do it (error messages, no result, etc).

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer just now, but [this post from a Unity developer explains the security restrictions here and suggests some possible work-arounds](https://forum.unity.com/threads/copy-paste-has-anyone-built-a-good-solution-for-this.401851/#post-2672497). Further down the thread, [a Unity-provided asset for this purpose](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/tutorial-projects/ime-input-for-unity-webgl-64933) is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works well but an attempt at a solution is to use the browser's copy and paste events. In paste pass that into Unity and append to the current InputField. On copy ask the inputfield to copy then pass unity's clipboard back to the browser

Here's some code and a working example

https://github.com/greggman/unity-webgl-copy-and-paste